# Serilog File sink not logging to file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

i am trying to get Serilog file sink working on my ASP.Net core 2.2 application based on the the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file). I am not able to see logs in my application. 
What am I missing?

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using System;

namespace Scrubber
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static string _environmentName;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        var iWebHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration.GetSection("Serilog"))
          .CreateLogger();
        Log.Logger = logger;
        Log.Information("Application starting");
        iWebHost.Run();
      }
      catch(Exception exception)
      {
        Log.Error(exception.ToString());
      }
      finally
      {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
      }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) =>
          {
            //config.ClearProviders();
            _environmentName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
          })
          .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

**Appsettings.development.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason is that the App didn't load the configuration at all.

Note you set up the configuration in the following way:

> ```
>    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
>      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
>      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
>     .Build();
> ```

1. You didn't set a base path for `ConfigurationBuilder`
2. You registered an `optional` json file by setting `optional: false`

As a result, if the json file doesn't reside in the right place, it fails silently.

I suggest you could change your code as below:

```
// get the real path 
//     or by reflection 
//     or by injection, 
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();       // assume the current directory

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(path)                                                       // set the right path
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)  //  make it required
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was just writing an answer for this too. `SetBasePath` is certainly a problem but there's a second problem: it should just be `ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)` because the Serilog configuration loader already assumes a *section* of `"Serilog"` which means it doesn't find any values.

Comment: If you want to fold that into your answer, I'll delete my comment. :)

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Thanks so much. But I think it's much better to leave your brilliant comment here as it indicates that it's you who helps us.

Comment: Thank you Kirk Larkin, @itminus, The changes that you suggested made the application logging work in Program.cs. However, the application did not redirect the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger output to Serilog.Log. Would I need to register the same in ConfigureServices?

Comment: I was able to get logging working throughout the application by adding the             iLoggingBuilder.AddSerilog(); line in public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)        
          .ConfigureLogging((webHostBuilderContext, iLoggingBuilder) =>
          {
            iLoggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
            _environmentName = webHostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
          })
          .UseStartup<Startup>();